# Setting level on AppenderRef or Logger in log4j2

Tags: logging, log4j2

I have a log4j2.xml config file with a single Logger, and a single Appender.

```
        <Logger name="LoggerName" additivity="false">
          <AppenderRef ref="AppenderName" level="info"/>
        </Logger>
```

```
        <!--  Single appender for logs -->
        <RollingFile name="AppenderName"
                     fileName="${basePath}/filename.csv.gz"
                     filePattern="${basePath}/filename.csv.gz.%d{yyyy-MM-dd-HH}.gz">
            <PatternLayout>
                <pattern>%m%n</pattern>
            </PatternLayout>
            <ThresholdFilter level="debug"/>
            <Policies>
                <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy/>
            </Policies>
            <DefaultRolloverStrategy fileIndex="nomax"/>
        </RollingFile>
```

This causes me to get no logs out when my program is running. I am attempting to log with an INFO level. However if I modify the Logger definition to be:

```
        <Logger name="LoggerName" additivity="false" level="info">
          <AppenderRef ref="AppenderName"/>
        </Logger>
```

...my logs start working again. As far as I can tell these two are both valid use cases, and given that I have a single Logger and a single Appender I think they should be equivalent.

I've also tried without the ThresholdFilter with no luck. What am I missing here?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every Logger has a logging level. If you omit the level keyword from the Logger declaration it defaults to ERROR.  The Level on the AppenderRef is different. It is really equivalent to adding a ThresholdFilter to the AppenderRef so if the level attribute is missing it is as if the ThresholdFilter isn't present. So omitting it there simply causes events to be passed on to the Appenders.